# How can I start a delayed sound on a page I'm about to navigate to?

Tags: javascript, html

My onclick function to start a delayed sound is never getting called, or it is, but no sound happens. It depends on where you navigate to in conjunction with the onclick, and from where you navigate. I understand that sounds are killed when you navigate away.
Below is the code. The func, little_ding(), arranges for do_bike_bell() to get called 1.5 sec later.

There's 4 cases. Cases A/B are from within home page, navigating to same/different page. C/D are similar, but are within a non home page.

Case A works fine. Case B calls little_ding(), but do_bike_bell() is never called. Cases C&D never even call little_ding(). This all w/ Chrome. Case B sort of works in FireFox: after you return to home page, do_bike_bell() is finally called and you hear it- not my intention.

```
// javascript
function do_bike_bell()
{
    //prompt("hello from do_bike_bell()");
    audio_ld.play();
    setTimeout(kill_bike_bell,4000);} // kill later to be sure

function little_ding() 
{   // prompt("hello from little_ding()");
    setTimeout(do_bike_bell,1500); }

// HTML. home_page.html calls same/level 2 page:
<a href="#id_in_same_file"   onclick="javascript:little_ding();">TEXT</a> // CASE A

<a href="poems/trinity.html" onclick="javascript:little_ding();">TEXT</a> // CASE B

// level 2 page calls same/level 3 page:
<a href="#id_in_same_file"   onclick="javascript:little_ding();">TEXT</a> // CASE C
<a href="lev3_page.html"     onclick="javascript:little_ding();">TEXT</a> // CASE D
```

// THe audio object is created like this, in main page's window.onload func():

```
audio_ld = document.createElement("audio");
audio_ld.src = "./sounds/bicycle-bell.mp3";
```

// level 3_page.html (didn't help):

```
<body onload="javascript:little_ding();">
```

Comment: What is the definition of `do_bike_bell` ?

Comment: I added do_bike_bell to post.